# Can't add package via SPM

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

Im trying to add the firebase packages via SPM, but not sure it can't access the remote:

[image]

- Already deleted the id_ed25519 key
- Already deleted all the derived data
- Already re started Xcode
- Already edited the git global file

none of that worked...