# Unable to add SPM packages

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

[image]

This issue doesn't affect existing packages that have been added. Those packages resolve just fine. Trying to add Firebase (or others) however gives me this error.

I've entered my username and hit OK but nothing happens. Cleared derived data, restarted Xcode, restarted MacBook, cleaned build...

I've also regenerated my id_rsa keys and uploaded to GitHub. Removed and re-added GitHub account on Xcode (and Sourcetree).

It looks to be the same as this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658262/cant-add-package-via-spm) - but that has no responses.

Comment: Try to establish whether your GitHub credentials are working at all.  Can you push to your own GitHub repo using Xcode? How about using the Terminal?